# PowerShell cannot find overload

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm attempting to use https://sshnet.codeplex.com/ to allow a PowerShell script to upload a file to a SFTP server. Everything appears to work, except it cannot find an overload of the method `UploadFile` and am stumped.

The definition of the method is here

```
TypeName   : Renci.SshNet.SftpClient
Name       : UploadFile
MemberType : Method
Definition : void UploadFile(System.IO.Stream input, string path, System.Action[uint64] uploadCallback),
             void UploadFile(System.IO.Stream input, string path, bool canOverride, System.Action[uint64] uploadCallback)
```

I'm trying to use this overload

```
UploadFile(System.IO.Stream input, string path, System.Action[uint64] uploadCallback)
```

The field `uploadCallback` is optional according to the documentation and isn't needed in my simple script, but even adding that in fails. The ways I've tried calling this with is as follows, they all fail.

How do I successfully call one of these methods? Examples of what I tried are below.

**Examples**

```
$client = New-Object Renci.SshNet.SftpClient($ftpHost, $ftpPort, $ftpUser, $ftpPass)
$client.Connect()

# ... get stream of file to upload here ...

$client.UploadFile($sourceStream, "$ftpPath$output")
```

Fails with

```
Cannot find an overload for "UploadFile" and the argument count: "2".
At F:\MyScript.ps1:170 char:2
+     $client.UploadFile($sourceStream, "$ftpPath$output")
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

The next attempts all fail with the same error message essentially

```
$action = [System.Action[uint64]]
$client.UploadFile($sourceStream, "$ftpPath$output", $action)
```

Error

```
Cannot find an overload for "UploadFile" and the argument count: "3".
At F:\MyScript.ps1:170 char:2
+     $client.UploadFile($sourceStream, "$ftpPath$output", $action)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Attempted with a `$null` 3rd parameter

```
$client.UploadFile($sourceStream, "$ftpPath$output", $null)
```

Failed with

```
Cannot find an overload for "UploadFile" and the argument count: "3".
At F:\MyScript.ps1:169 char:2
+     $client.UploadFile($sourceStream, "$ftpPath$output", $null)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Comment: Try `$client.UploadFile($sourceStream, "$ftpPath$output", [Action[uint64]]$null)`.  Also, is $sourceStream a stream i.e. does `$sourceStream -is [System.IO.Stream]` return True?

Comment: It might help to trim this post down. It's got a lot to go through to get to the meat of the question. Maybe even reorganize it so some more important details are at the beginning.

Comment: @KeithHill That was the problem, I was passing a `StreamReader` instead of a `Stream`. If you fill out an answer I'll accept it, thank you.

Comment: Cool.  I created an answer from the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try giving PowerShell a bit more help by providing the type info as cast in the method call e.g.:

```
$client.UploadFile($sourceStream, "$ftpPath$output", [Action[uint64]]$null)
```